# How to log all external tcp traffic made by Django app (api calls to 3rd party apis)

Tags: python, django, networking, tcp, middleware

I have a django app that makes use of some 3rd party API's, analytics tools apis (mixpanel, google analytics, etc), APNS, GCM etc.

I need some way of logging all the requests made by my django app (incoming/outgoing traffic) between the django app and these 3rd party apis. Basically all the HTTP requests made by the python process itself. I am aware that using Wireshark I can achieve it but then it will show requests made by other processes as well (other running services).

(I have used New Relic, and new relic does show certain stats regarding external requests made from the Django app)

I have searched lots of forums/ docs but can't find mention of something like this. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: I'm doing development on mac osX 10.10.5, and using Ubuntu 14.04 for production servers?

Comment: have you seen this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101522/tcp-dump-outgoing-connection-packets

Comment: Yes but its not helping. Is there a way i can hijack the python process and record all the http traffic?